# Is there practice to train language-to-code transformer (multi-modal transformer) using uni-modal pretrained models-transformers?

Tags: machine-learning-model, transformer, pretraining

Language-to-code transformation/generation require multiple skills - language and reasoning skills to digest the core problem from the natural language specification. And programming language knowledge. There are separate pret-trained models for the language and code. And there are some multimodal language+code models (e.g. from stackoverflow, Github issues, etc.). My question is - is there traning of multimodal models that rely on the supervision by unimodal models solely?